# Change highlight color in QWebView

Tags: c++, qt4, qwebview

I want to change to color in which text is highlighted when the findText() method is used. This color has nothing to do with user selected text. I have tried CSS as well as setting a QPalette. All occurences are always highlighted in yellow.

Comment: Please provide some code which is causing the issue.

Comment: Have a look at the [QPalatte-property](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwebpage.html#palette-prop) of QWebPage.

Comment: @bash.d
I'm using the findText() method of QWebView. It works as expected but I would like to change to color in which text is highlighted. When using a QPalette the color for highlighted text is only used for text highlighted by the user (e.g. with the mouse) and not for the text highlighted by findText().
I also tried to set a new CSS rule but it had the same effect as the QPalette. 
The code I'm using is:
`pWebView->findText("someText",QWebPage::HighlightAllOccurrences);`

The CSS rule I tried is:
`::selection{background: #ff0000;}`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, but unfortunately this does not work. The highlighted text is always yellow. Seems like this is a hard coded somewhere in webkit.

Comment: This is possible... Maybe someone else knows something. Stay tuned!

Comment: Have you considered sub-classing QWebView and reimplementing findText? I don't have the Qt source code in front of me, but you should be able to capture QWebView::findText and then change its display color.

Answer (score 1):

I've been searching for this as well, and it seems like it's [hardcoded](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtwebkit.git/tree/Source/WebCore/rendering/RenderTheme.cpp#n1214) deep inside WebKit:

```
Color RenderTheme::platformInactiveTextSearchHighlightColor() const
{
    return Color(255, 255, 0); // Yellow.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I really have the same problem. But the good news: Setting the style sheet helps at least to change the fg/bk color.

```
m_browser->setStyleSheet("QWebView { 
    selection-background-color: blue; selection-color: white; }");
```

But this is not the whole truth because it only changes the fg/bk color of the currently found text. No idea how to change the fg/bk color of all occurences.

Axel